# How does Google+ contact process glass shared timeline items?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I am testing out the mirror api and so far I have a sample app running nicely.

The issue I am having is that I added a menu item for the action 'SHARE' but when I try to share the timeline card created by my app to Google+ it posts an empty Google+ post. The only text in the Google+ post is #throughglass. The contents of the timeline card is some simple html (see below) which renders find on glass. I also set the speakable text which works great with the 'READ_ALOUD' menu action. What gives on the 'SHARE' action, am I missing something?

[Link to Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+CarltonDennis/posts/KLMD39ErN71)

Timeline Item html:

```
<article class="auto-paginate">
<section>
  <p class="text-auto-size">
    Hello Word.
  </p>
</section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each application is free to choose what, from the shared timeline item, it will use as part of the share command. The Google+ Glassware appears to use the `text` field only when sharing a textual item and ignores the `html` field.

(This makes some sense. Google+ can't display the HTML formatting, so it chooses to go with the text that it knows should be good.)

When you're writing Glassware, you should make sure both the `text` and `html` (and `speakableText`, for that matter) fields contain the correct representation of your item.